# Выравнивание сообщения атрибута "required" по левому краю

Tags: input, messagebox, html, style, html5

Возможно ли задать выравнивание сообщения атрибута "required" по левому краю в chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно Вас понял:

```
<form>
<input required>
<button>GO</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input{float:left; box-shadow:none;}
```

Можно и абсолютно отпозиционировать по левому краю:

```
input{position:absolute; left:0; box-shadow:none;}
```

Или Вы вообще можете стилизовать именно только input с required и выравнять только их по левому краю:

```
input:required {
 float:left;
}
```

Еще, как вариант можно input добавить в div и позиционировать div. Да, Вы вопрос корректнее (подробнее) задавайте. Можно, как вариант javascript'ом искать поле с required и позиционировать.